# Verizon Software Keeps Re-Installing itself

Tags: malware, device-firmware, google-pixel, verizon, baseband

i have a Pixel 4XL,

baseband version g8150-00123-220402-B-8399852
i think its American , but i have installed the Australian Firmware on the device , after a Factory Reset , and installation of Lineage OS,

this Verizon software keeps reinstalling... can anyone clear up if this is spyware hidden ( i got the phone from a dodgy supplier online, *had bad reviews*)
i want to remove it , yet it keeps reinstalling after multiple wipes.. i have erased slot a and b , reflashed recovery , reflashed firmware.

i intially thought it was reinstalling as it was linked to the baseband but from what i understand installing the Australian firmware should remove this system app ..
can anyone tell me how i can completely wipe this phone so this is removed. Do i need to edit the kernal to change the baseband someone at the phone shop suggested editing the Build Prop is this correct ? and if so how does one go about this.

The apk's listed below keep reinstalling no matter how many times i reinstall FW,wipe etc.
it leads me to believe it is malware. Any Help would be greatly appriciated

AppDirectedSMS
com.verizon.services
source directory - /product/priv-app/AppDirectedSMSService

---

com.verizon.obdm_permissions
source directory - /system_ext/priv-app/OBDM_Permissions

---

D-MAT
com.verizon.obdm

source directory - /system_ext/priv-app/obdm_stub
__
My Verizon Services
com.verizon.mips.services
source directory - /system_Ext/priv-app/MyVerizonServices

my running services shows these two process running constantly on Lineage 0S 19.1
com.qualcomm.qcrilmsgtunnel

com.qualcomm.atfwd

Comment: I think we had a question about self-installing apps where those apps were located on a separate partition within the system. May be this is also the source of the apps in your case. Have you tried to flash the last official image provided by Google? Those images not only contain system and empty user partition but often images for additional partitions. If you have rooted the phone you can search for partitions where the APK file(s) are located that are automatically installed.

Comment: i think this sounds about right !, i was reading someone else had a similiar problem , they described it as almost like a hidden partition, Yes i have flashed the official firmware from google. it says the APK'S are installed as a priv-app , how exactly would i locate where they are stored ? , and how would i go about deleting them so they dont come back after reflashes. 
Do i perhaps need to flash fastboot erase modem 
fastboot flash modem " or maybe fastboot erase carrier ?